# No network after unplugging cable and plugging it back in

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, kubuntu

I have:

- **OS:** Kubuntu (x64)
- **Distributor ID:**  Ubuntu
- **Description:** Ubuntu 14.04
- **LTS Release:** 14.04
- **Codename:** trusty
- **Kernel:** 3.13.0-29-generic

My network card works OK when I boot up my laptop, but if I unplug the cable and plug it back in, I can't get it to work :(

I tried this. First get the Kernel driver identifier:

```
lspci -k

...

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
...
```

Tried to remove the network module from kernel:

```
sudo rmmod r8169
```

In the syslog I got:

```
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC ModemManager[918]: <info>  (net/eth0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [20 10 36]
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <warn> (6) failed to find interface name for index
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <error> [1413382433.46921] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 15 09:13:53 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
```

Then, tried to add the previous module to the kernel:

```
sudo modprobe r8169
```

And syslog showed:

```
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.000615] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.000627] r8169 0000:01:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.000714] r8169 0000:01:00.0 (unregistered net_device): unknown MAC, using family default
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.010824] r8169 0000:01:00.0 (unregistered net_device): rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.010879] r8169 0000:01:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.011165] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: RTL8101e at 0xffffc90000c6a000, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, XID 9cf0f8ff IRQ 43
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-12) Object not found
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): carrier is OFF
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'r8169' ifindex: 7)
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC NetworkManager[1126]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 15 09:14:05 dte-PC kernel: [89904.017022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Oct 15 09:14:07 dte-PC ModemManager[918]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0': not supported by any plugin
```

But it does not matter, still no network (it shows that the cable is unplugged or it can't get an ip address).

I always have to reboot my laptop in order to make it work again.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: try `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I tried that, but it does not work.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Hi bodhi, just wanted to tell you that I had this problem the other day and I tried your suggestion with a different command: `sudo service network-manager restart` and it worked! If you put it as an answer to my question, I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

resolved the problem.